# How to open "Go to Definition/Implementation" in regular tab

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio (any year), you can open a file by using "Go to Definition/Implementation".  When you do this, the file is opened in a tab on the far right side of the screen:
[image]

I find this to be annoying.  What's the point of opening the tab way over there?  Why not just open it here?
[image]

(A) is there some reason or benefit for it opening way the eff over there?
(B) is there a way to have it open amongst the rest of the tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A: Depends, if it's from your code than it's not very beneficial but if it's not then it helps you separate from the files in the project and the files in different libraries

B: Yes,click that little icon and the tab will be moved to the rest of the tabs

[image: the icon to press]

Comment: Ha!  I didn't know that little icon did that!  Franky, I can't see sh*t, so I miss little icons like this.